# How can I sort Items in a database created chart in PHP?

Tags: php, datatables

I have created a database which contains people from a run with the amount of rounds which they ran. After that I created this script which creates a html chart.

The script:

```
<?php
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=HIDDEN;dbname=HIDDEN", 'HIDDEN', 'HIDDEN') or die ("Verbindung nicht möglich");
  $query_temp = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM runners");
  $query_temp->bindParam(':id', $id);
  $id = 1;
  $query_temp->execute();

  echo '<table class="table table-hover">';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<th>ID</th>';
  echo '<th>Name</th>';
  echo '<th>Runden</th>';
  echo '</tr>';
  while($id_table = $query_temp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$id_table['runner_id'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$id_table['runner_name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$id_table['runner_rounds'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';
?>
```

The Database:
http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/WklMcTG.png

Screenshot how it looks:
http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/v2zbOSu.png

Now I want to give the users the ability to sort the people for their amount of rounds which they ran. Like the most person is at the first place. How can I do this?

Comment: sounds like you want datatables. https://www.datatables.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this you need a **js** plugin and turn the HTML dynamic. There is a lot of plugins to make it and  will list some of them to you:

1. [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html)
2. [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

Each plugin work differently, but in the end they have almost the same behaviour, then you need to check the documentation of them and try to run...

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was searching :D

Answer (score 0):

You should use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) with jQuery